# File server load balancing .Net and Sync the file servers

Tags: .net, fileserver

Designing an application which as 2 web servers load balanced and 2 app servers load balanced and Active passive db servers.
The technology stack is asp.net MVC, WCF and sql server.
One of the requirements is to upload the images and retrieve it as per the need. It is not a social network site kind of thing; it is an application going to used by 1000 users approx.
I have couple of questions,

### Can I have file servers under/below Load balancer?

### How the sync the file servers? Any tool automatically do this?

Please let me know if more info is need

Thanks